# what is the correct way to define Async

Tags: spring, spring-boot

It seems that both  are working. But should I annotate @Async in interface or implementation class?

```
public interface Test {

    @Async
    void A()

    void B();
}

public class TestImpl implements Test {

    @Override
    void A(){}

    @Override
    @Async
    void B(){}
}
```

Comment: Surely it depends on whether all `B()` need to be async or not?

Comment: ok. so the implementation class has a choice to run override method async or not.

Comment: No, if it's async in the interface, it's async for the implementation. if it's not async in the interface, you can make it async in the implementation if you so choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To flesh out your example --

```
public interface Test{
    @Async
    void A()

    void B();
}

public class TestImpl implements Test {
    @Override
    void A(){}

    @Override
    @Async
    void B(){}
}

public class AnotherTestImpl implements Test {
    @Override
    void A(){}

    @Override
    void B(){}
}
```

For both `TestImpl` and `AnotherTestImpl`, the `A()` method is async -- that's inherited from the interface.

On the other hand, `B()` is not async in the interface. `TestImpl` declares its implementation as async, so it's async there. But `AnotherTestImpl` does not, so it's also not async there.

```
| Method | Interface | TestImpl | AnotherTestImpl |
|--------|-----------|----------|-----------------|
| A()    | async     | async    | async           |
| B()    | not async | async    | not async       |
```

Basically, if you declare it on the interface method, it will be inherited by all implementors.